# Trying to extract contents from the website by iterating over pages using Python's BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract contents from this post "https://community.diabetes.org/discuss/viewtopic/3/13319" and to iterate over post pages to continue scraping, but the next pages rendered by some JS code. Any ideas how to solve it?

```
import requests

url = 'https://community.diabetes.org/discuss/viewcategory/3/13319'

r = requests.get(url)

text = r.text

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")

Title = []

title = soup.find_all("h3",{"class":"forum-post-subject"})


 for i in title:
        Title.append(i.text.strip())
```

Comment: The link you provided shows Error 404.

Comment: Sorry I just changed the link Please try now

Comment: Try to checkout frameworks for web scraping, like Scrapy for example https://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is dynamic i.e a frontend script updates the page, thus, you will need to use a browser manipulation tool such as `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from collections import namedtuple
import re
def package_responses(data):
   post = namedtuple('post', ['title', 'author', 'date', 'content'])
   new_data = [data[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]
   return [post(a, re.findall('(?<=Posted by)[\w\W]+(?=\son)', b)[0], re.findall('(?<=on\s)[\w\W]+', b)[0], c) for a, b, c in new_data]
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://community.diabetes.org/discuss/viewtopic/3/13319')
main_page = [i.text for i in soup(d.page_source, 'lxml').find_all(re.compile('h3|a|p|div'), {'class':re.compile('forum\-post\-subject|author|content')})]
final_data = {1:package_responses(main_page)}
page_links = d.find_elements_by_class_name('pager-num')
for i, page_link in enumerate(page_links, start=2):
   try:
     page_link.click()
     main_page = [i.text for i in soup(d.page_source, 'lxml').find_all(re.compile('h3|a|p|div'), {'class':re.compile('forum\-post\-subject|author|content')})]
     final_data[i] = package_responses(main_page)
   except:
     page_links.extend(d.find_elements_by_class_name('pager-num'))

print(final_data[1])
```

Output:

```
[post(title=u'\n\nfree style libre now available?\n', author=u' maryd98', date=u'Dec  1, 2017 10:45 am\n', content=u"(Mary's comments in blue, below; comments in black are from Kashi's mom\u200d )\nKashi's mom is unable to post (again). She has sent me a PM asking me to post this for her:\nI think people will want to know that the free style libre is now on the market. I signed up to be notified and I was (on Monday I think.)\xa0 They didn't give info about price or what insurances will cover this. They just said to talk with your doctor as to suitability, ask for\xa0 a prescription from your doctor and go to one of the participating pharmacies. The pharmacies listed are Walmart, CVS, Krogar, Rite Aid and Walgreens. I'm seriously surorised that more of you weren't notified or more publicity wasn't involved.\nI did go to Walmart to get information and discovered that they had heard but that they didn't have the product nor pricing, etc. Info yet.I don't know, but it sounds to me like Kashi's mom was notified before the thing is actually available. Here^ is her message, in any case.\n\xa0"), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' powerwalker2', date=u'Dec  1, 2017 10:07 pm\n', content=u'Thanks, Mary and Kashi\'s Mom!\xa0 I also received that notice, and the thought of being able to just\xa0"swipe" the reader across the sensor led me to post this under "Diabetes Technology...":\nHave you all thought about\xa0significant times at which you\xa0would want to "swipe" your Freestyle (Libre)\xa0reader over the sensor\xa0and get your reading?\xa0 I was thinking of these 8 times, and have started trying to test at those times in order to have some readings for comparison, eventually:\n1. fasting\n2. after each of 3 meals/before each of 3 exercise workouts\n3. after each of 3 exercise workouts/before each of 3 meals\n4. bedtime\nHOWEVER, although my Walgreens said they could order the Freestyle Libre, my doc is having a problem with writing a prescription for it, because it\'s not in the office\'s\xa0electronic system, and he can\'t just write a prescription for it on a piece of paper like in the old days, but is going to look into the situation.\xa0 I gave him lots of papers\xa0I printed-out with info about\xa0the Libre, and with various\xa0phone numbers which have done me no good so far.\xa0 Is this type of electronic system also being used by the rest of your doctors?\xa0 So frustrating!\xa0 Freestyle Libre bottom line\xa0-- "New" is one thing, but "Nonexistent" is another.\xa0 Where is it?\xa0 In the cloud???!!!!!!!!\xa0 Stuck in Europe and the UK?????????'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' maryd98', date=u'Dec  2, 2017  3:38 pm\n', content=u"I think you were smart to post on that other thread, Nancy -- that's probably what I should have done instead of starting a new one.\xa0\nIf anyone reading this wants more info, please go to the other thread. It has quite a few comments from people who have info about the free style libre:https://community.diabetes.org/discuss/viewtopic/3/13128"), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' candlesflame', date=u'Dec  2, 2017  4:11 pm\n', content=u'who gets the fun job of inserting the round disk on your outer arm and MY GOSH that looks like a long needle in middle of white disk that goes on your arm ...soooo you swipe the free style device over it...anyone here have something like this...\ni get nervous when something just comes out...i want hundreds of Guinea pigs errrr patients to test it first..wink..i like being last in line...but it does look great....today i smashed my hand in rock garden doing front yard that would be great to not try to fumble with test strips and have this gizmo instead,,,i could see using it if your recovering from a serious illness or accident and your hooked up to ivs or what not..'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' hangry', date=u'Dec  2, 2017  5:08 pm\n', content=u'Inserting reader onto arm.\xa0 I think I have several relatives who will compete for the honor.\xa0 All the while telling me how much they love me.'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' powerwalker2', date=u'Dec  2, 2017  6:03 pm\n', content=u'\ncandlesflame:who gets the fun job of inserting the round disk on your outer arm and MY GOSH that looks like a long needle in middle of white disk that goes on your arm ...soooo you swipe the free style device over it...anyone here have something like this...\ni get nervous when something just comes out...i want hundreds of Guinea pigs errrr patients to test it first..wink..i like being last in line...but it does look great....today i smashed my hand in rock garden doing front yard that would be great to not try to fumble with test strips and have this gizmo instead,,,i could see using it if your recovering from a serious illness or accident and your hooked up to ivs or what not..\n\nWell.\xa0 You\'re not supposed to look at the needle.\xa0 \xa0 But I think that the needle is just what helps insert the thin filament that goes under the skin, and that supposedly we can\'t "feel".\xa0 Maybe we can find out more about that, but there are hundreds of videos on inserting the sensor and swiping the reader on YouTube -- all by our friends in England, who\'ve been using it for years.\xa0 Looks like an easy "do-it-yourself" job, but I don\'t know, yet.\n'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' powerwalker2', date=u'Dec  2, 2017  6:09 pm\n', content=u"\nhangry:\nInserting reader onto arm.\xa0 I think I have several relatives who will compete for the honor.\xa0 All the while telling me how much they love me.\n\nLOL\xa0 From what I've seen posted by all the Brits on YouTube, there's really nothing to it.\xa0 Just lift your arm with the beefiest triceps, and stick it on.\xa0 Maybe with some firmness, until it clicks.\xa0 Takes only seconds, apparently.\xa0 Then\xa0the sensor\xa0lasts for 10 days (2 weeks in England -- where they don't even need a prescription).\n"), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' jpg391', date=u'Dec  3, 2017 11:35 am\n', content=u"Just to bring everyone back down to Earth. Most insurance companies, including Medicare, don't cover CGMs for type 2 people. Your doctor may have to get a prior authorization in order to write a prescription and have insurance cover it."), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' TVMangum27406', date=u'Dec  4, 2017  7:07 am\n', content=u'I actually did a short term study of the Libre Pro earlier this year for my insurance company and employer. I did not feel anything when the sensor was put on me. My endocrinologist has been working to get me the Libre since they came out last Monday. When I checked with Abbott on Friday they told me that the Rx could be sent to either Abbott\u2019s prescription retrieval system or straight to the pharmacy. Sending it back to Abbott would take 10-14 days to process instead of sending straight to pharmacy where it might take a day or two. I hope to hear something from someone today.'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' TVMangum27406', date=u'Dec  4, 2017  9:19 am\n', content=u'In case anyone needs these, here is the NDC (National Drug Code) for both the Libre sensor and the reader.\nReader: 57599000021\nSensor: 57599000019'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' Goodgirl08', date=u'Dec  4, 2017 11:45 am\n', content=u'tv man, do you know how long the needle really is?  '), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' powerwalker2', date=u'Dec  4, 2017  7:44 pm\n', content=u'\nTVMangum27406:\nIn case anyone needs these, here is the NDC (National Drug Code) for both the Libre sensor and the reader.\nReader: 57599000021\nSensor: 57599000019\n\nThank you!!\xa0 Please tell us where that info can be found, so we can give\xa0it to our doctors.\n'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' TVMangum27406', date=u'Dec  4, 2017  8:11 pm\n', content=u'The NDC was given to me by Customer Service at Abbott. If I remember correctly the needle/filament is 5 mm long and less that 0.40 mm in thickness. More info can be found here,\xa0https://www.myfreestyle.com/provider/freestyle-libre-product.\nMy system should be at my local CVS sometime tomorrow.'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' powerwalker2', date=u'Dec  4, 2017 11:32 pm\n', content=u'\nTVMangum27406:\nThe NDC was given to me by Customer Service at Abbott..........................\n\nThanks, TVMangum!\xa0 So, did those code numbers help your doctor in being able to write the prescriptions?\n'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' TVMangum27406', date=u'Dec  5, 2017  6:59 am\n', content=u'They helped to make sure that the right items were on the Rx.it also helped with insurance coverage. It is so new that most big box pharmacies know very little about it. The sad part is that the independent pharmacies know a lot about the Libre but they cannot order or dispense them for patients.'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u" Kashi's mom", date=u'Dec  6, 2017  9:22 am\n', content=u'Any news re cost?\nMMarMMarjoMMarMMarjoriMMarMMarjoMMarMMarjorie'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' hangry', date=u'Dec  6, 2017 12:19 pm\n', content=u"Wonder if it will bring down the price for other companies CGM's?\xa0 \xa0\xa0\nFor the US people, I think watch here for info and prices.\nhttps://www.freestylelibre.us/"), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' morrisolder', date=u'Dec  7, 2017  1:11 am\n', content=u"Today, on 24 hour sports talk radio, I heard an ad addressed to Dexcom 5 users, which talked about how inaccurate their glucose readings might be if they use acetaminophin, or meds containing acetaminophin (they specifically mentioned robitussin).\xa0 I thought ti was a recall or warning\xa0\xa0 --they did say it can cause false high readings, which could lead to taking in too much insulin to compensate, thus causing low---but wait, the announcer said, now there's Freestyle Libte, with no acetaminophin probelm!\nThe ad did not mention cost, ease of use, or zero in on the advantages people in this post have been drooling over interested in\nI thought, hmm, interesting marketing approach..."), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' Caloh', date=u'Dec  7, 2017  9:37 am\n', content=u'To find out the cost, phone\xa0 your pharmacy.\xa0 It is now supposed to be available at pharmacies in the US.'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' Caloh', date=u'Dec  9, 2017  2:32 pm\n', content=u'My FreeStyle Libre arrived in the mail and I am now using it.\xa0 The kit, containing, 2 senors (each good for 2 weeks of readings), a reader with touchscreen and USB port, and cables came to $227 Canadian;\xa0 additional sensors are $89 each.\xa0 I loved Hangry\'s comment about how relatives would compete for the honor of inserting the sensor\'s needle in one\'e arm.\xa0 I thought of my daughter and had her do it for me.\xa0 I read that someone\'s sensor fell off and I wanted to be sure it was put on firmly.\nI am on day 3 of using it.\xa0 Applying the sensor was painless.\xa0 When we opened the package my daughter said "Wow, look at the size of that needle!", which did not make me happy.\xa0 But I did not feel it at all when she put it on my arm.\xa0 The sensor has stayed on with no problems during my morning showers.\xa0 I was worried about getting a reaction to the adhesive (I get a rash from adhesive\'s on my abdomen) but so far no problems.\nThe manual reminds you that the sensor is testing interstitial blood and readings may differ from meter results, especially at times of rapid blood glucose changes.\xa0 The manual warns that taken ascorbic acid (vitamin C) can raise the readings, and salicylic acid (in aspirin, some pain relievers and some skin creams) can lower the readings.\nSo far, I am testing with my Freestyle Lite meter 4 times a day as well as taking many, many readings with the Libre.\xa0 Silly me, but I find it fun to turn it on and wave it over the sensor on my arm.\xa0 The manual says the readings can be off by 20%, however it has been closer to 3-5% of my meter readings.\xa0 The Libre seems to be lower than my meter\'s readings but not by much.\xa0 The Libre\'s reading also have an arrow, pointing up if the readings are rising;\xa0 pointing down if the readings are falling;\xa0 and pointing straight ahead if the readings are steady or changing slowly.\xa0 The reader can also be used as a blood glucose meter but only if one uses the Freestyle Precision Pro test strips (which I don\'t have) and it can also test for ketones.\xa0 It can remind you to test (if you set it to do so), but it does not give warnings if readings are too low.\nThe manual says not to use the Libre\'s sensor\'s readings for judging insulin doses,\xa0\xa0 It recommends using the Libre\'s meter instead, which is built into the reader. \xa0 Also, a health care professional has access to a code that can make the senor do insulin calculations.\xa0 After the code is entered, one can set up to 3 insulin-to-carb ratios (depending on time of day), correction factors, and a bunch of other stuff which I am not doing since I am not working with a health care professional.\xa0 My family doctor OKed my buying this but will offer no technical support.\nWhen I use the Libre, the reader also shows me a graph of my lastest 8 hour readings.\xa0\nIt comes with cables to charge the sensor (about once a week) and to get your computer printer to print out all your data.\xa0 You can do log info, like meals, meds, etc. on the reader.\nSo far, it has been fun and it looks like I stay in my range pretty much all the time.\xa0 Makes me smile.\n20+ years a type 2 and no new complications since diagnosis.'), post(title=u'\nRe: free style libre now available?\n', author=u' morrisolder', date=u'Dec  9, 2017  6:35 pm\n', content=u'I heard the ad again --the phrase I could not remember was that the Freestyle Libre is the only conitnuous monitoring device that avoids"acetaminophen interfrence."\nStrange they should emphasize that, when apparently,according to Caloh, "The manual warns that taken ascorbic acid (vitamin C) can raise the readings, and salicylic acid (in aspirin, some pain relievers and some skin creams) can lower the readings." So Dexcom has acetaminophen interference, but this has aspirin and Vitamin C interference--seems like an even trade off.\nPer Caloh\'s description, they should be able tmarket instead based on cost, ease of use, lack of needed calibration, etc. etc...')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to get dynamic content, you could use phantomJS for compile JavaScript and later take the content, or Selenium(easier). If you have more time, you could take the requests urls from JavaScript code and make It with requests module.

By the way, i recommend use lxml module instead beautiful soup, it's faster.

Comment: Thank you all, So, I'm able to extract the title for the first page, I just needed to know if it was possible to iterate through pages 2,3,4 and so on using only beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code has to get 'href' in order to be able to iter, for this, you should change the following lines

```
>>> title = soup.find_all("a")
[<a class="site-page-link" href="/unlog.php" target="_self" title="Login">Login</a>,....]
>>> kk=[i.get('href') for i in title]
>>> len(kk)
26
```

the out is:[image]